# Simplify this expression related to factorials

Tags: combinatorics

Was computing a combinatorics problem when I encountered this expression:

$6\cdot5! \,+\, 5\cdot4! \,+\, 4\cdot3!\,+\, 3\cdot2! \,+\,  3\cdot2! \,+\,  2\cdot1!$

Maybe I'm missing something obvious -- is there a way to simply this expression?

Comment: Except $\;6!+5!+4!+3!+2!$, I don't see…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(n+1)(n!)=(n+1)!$ Past that, I don't see much simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only wanted *one* 3⋅2! term (rather than two):

6⋅5! + 5⋅4! + 4⋅3! + 3⋅2! + 2⋅1! =

6! + 5⋅4! + 4! + 3⋅2! + 2! =

6! + 6⋅4! + 4⋅2!

Further you can make it:
30⋅4! + 6⋅4! + 4!/3 = (36 1/3)⋅4!

It all depends on what you mean or want by "simplify".

If you *did* want the extra term, it can regrouped similarly to reduce the number of terms.

(6⋅5! + 5⋅4!) + (4⋅3! + 3⋅2! + 3⋅2!) +2⋅1! =

7⋅5! + 6⋅3! + 2! and so on.